# Error fatal usando PHP y mysql

Tags: php, base-de-datos

vengo a pedir ayuda ya que he estado practicando php y me tocó el conectar una BD usando PDO pero me aparece el siguente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la verdad no se como hacerlo ya que vi tutoriales y muy pocos usan pdo y los que lo usan lo usan en el mismo script del html
Este es mi codigo php con la clase database y el metodo para conectar la base de datos, para desconectarse de la base de datos y para hacer consultas

```
<?phpclass Database{
private $PDOLocal;
private $user="root";
private $password="";
private $server="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ejemplo_php;";

function conectarDB()
{
    try{
        $PDOLocal=new PDO($this->server,$this->user,$this->password);
        print("Conexion hecha");
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->GetMessage();

    }
}
function desconectarDB()
{
    try{
        $this->PDOLocal=null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->GetMessage();
        
    }
}
function seleccionar($cadenaSQL)
{
    try{
        $resultado=$this->PDOLocal->query($cadenaSQL);
        $tupla=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $tupla;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->GetMessage();
        
    }
    
}
```

}
Mientras que este es el script de la pagina en donde quisiera que se imprima una tabla con los datos de la tabla tt

```
    <div class="container"> 
        <h1 align="center">Clientes</h1>    
        <?php
        include 'database.php';
        $conexion = new Database();
        $conexion ->conectarDB();
        $consulta ="select * from tt";
        $conexion ->seleccionar($consulta); 
        echo "<table class='table-hover'>
        <thead class='thead-dark>
        <tr>
        <th>t1</th><th>t2</th><th>t3</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>";
        foreach($tabla as $fila)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" .$fila->t1. "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $fila->t2. "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $fila->t3."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody>
        </table>";
        $conexion->desconectarDB();
        ?>
```

si me pueden ayudar explicandome o mandandome un tutorial se los agradecería mucho:(

Comment: Este enlace responde tu pregunta por el tutorial. [(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) es muy difícil conseguir algo mejor. Procura no hacer "mixtura" de php y html es muy ineficiente. Prepara todo lo que puedas en unas pocas variables de salida y luego vuélcalo (sírvelo) con un par de **echo**

Comment: Veo un detalle en tu código: Aunque PDO suele venir habilitado por defecto, **siempre** se debe crear una referencia explícita antes de usarlo, mediante la cláusula `use PDO;` y el archivo en que declaras la clase Database no la tiene. Prueba a insertar esa línea inmediatamente antes de class. Sospecho que es suficiente para arreglar el problema. **Pero: Tu código crea agujeros de seguridad.** lee el tutorial